# What could be the problem in To-do app using Streamlit in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, streamlit, contextmanager, filenotfounderror

#### to-dos.py

```py
import streamlit as st
import get_todos

todos = get_todos.getTodos()

def add_todos():
    todo1 = st.session_state["new_todo"] + "\n"
    todos.append(todo1)
    get_todos.writeTodos(todos)


st.title("My TO-DO App")
...
```

#### get_todos.py

```py
def getTodos():
    with open("docs.txt", "r") as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    return data


def writeTodos(adder):
    with open("docs.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(adder)
```

I built a TO-DO App in Python using streamlit
While performing this task in terminal, it's continuously showing
`'FileNotFoundError'` meanwhile the file actually exist.

What could be the problem ?
Any syntax error? or Logical Error?

**Error Traceback:**
[image]

**My project structure is shown below:**
[image]

Comment: In which directory is the file located?. If it is in same directory you can try this `./docs.txt`

Comment: @JamiuShaibu No it's not working.
I could also be wrong! Please mention clearly what to change and not.
Moreover, it's in lib folder

Comment: I am sorry I can't help and neither will any one can if we don't know the structure of your directories. I think you should rather make your question more clear my providing the structure of your directories..

Comment: @JamiuShaibu I am providing the screenshot of the structure of my directories
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyLLF8EIYN7DX0QhV2om4ZvfNpNhwlnT/view?usp=share_link)

Please check

Comment: Your files are not in lib folder, they are in venv and venv shouldn't contain any of the files I saw in your screeshot. Your structure is not appropriate.  I will recommend you [visit pycharm project structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html) to restructure your project. It might feel like a pain on the neck but I bet it worth it. Those files should rather be in `samik` folder.

Comment: @JamiuShaibu Thanks a lot for helping. 
As soon as I placed the files in the Samik folder, it worked.

Comment: I am glad it worked, I edited the question to make it more specific and reusable so it could be beneficial to someone who happened to face same or similar issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of virtual environments or `venv` is to manage settings and dependencies of a particular project regardless of other Python projects. virtualenv tool comes bundled with PyCharm, so the user doesn't need to install it. It is always found in the project directory named `venv` which should be a unique folder design to fulfil a specific purpose.

**Note: No external file(s) should be added to the `venv` folder.**

This clearly indicates that your structure is not appropriate. I will recommend you *[visit pycharm project structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html)* to read more about **configuration of virtual environments**. You should restructure your project properly. It might feel like a pain on the neck but I bet it worth it.

**Attention:**
All the external files you added to `venv` should rather be in your `samik` folder which is your project main folder.